# Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug' with Wheel Picker

Tags: android

this is my first post at stackoverflow, unfortunately it is a question about a bug :'(. After I added my project on Github to Android Studio, it builds fine, but when I build the apk to run on my phone, it gives me the error:

```
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/aigestudio/wheelpicker/BuildConfig.class
```

I searched online for the solution but they were saying something about a duplicate class, and rebuilding the project, but all of those did not work for me.
Here is my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.tiena.amsconnection"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile project(':WheelPicker')

    compile project(path: ':expanding-view')

    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
            def requested = details.requested
            if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
                if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                    details.useVersion '26.0.1'
                }
            }
        }
    }

    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.2.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.22.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'cn.aigestudio.wheelpicker:WheelPicker:1.1.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.github.techery:properratingbar:0.0.5'
    compile 'com.ramotion.foldingcell:folding-cell:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.+'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Please help me :'( this is my first big project. Thank you

Comment: Are you adding WheelPicker as a project and also compiling its library?

Comment: i added it as a module here's the link https://github.com/AigeStudio/WheelPicker

Comment: Remove compile 'cn.aigestudio.wheelpicker:WheelPicker:1.1.2' from your dependency.

Comment: @R.R.M Probably you are perfect .

Comment: Thanks @IntelliJ Amiya  :)

Comment: I really need to upvote your answer or mark it in some way @R.R.M, I owe you 2 cups of Starbucks coffee, any way to upvote your comment?

Comment: Ok then I m putting it as answer :D

Comment: Hahahaha... Yeah... Sure... If @Duy Hiếu Vũ is ready to pay your bill :P :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove below line from your dependency:

```
compile 'cn.aigestudio.wheelpicker:WheelPicker:1.1.2'
```

Comment: Well I have less than 15 reputation so I can't upvote your answer :'(, but I've marked it as the answer anyways, Thanks very much

Comment: It's Ok.. It means alot... :)